# How to validate if a checkbox is checked and if true generate code?

Tags: javascript

I am new to stackoverflow I usually do well finding my own answers, I'm not a javascript pro by no means, my question is probably a simple answer to some...lol

My example code looks at a text field with name input10 and then generates the code in the generator.  For this I don't believe I need a text field; a checkbox would be much better and I would add value to the checkbox value="telephone=no"

What do I have to add to my code to work with a checkbox?

**Example Code**

```
if (form.input10.value != "") {
      form.generator.value +="<meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"" +
      form.input10.value + "\">\n"; 
}
```

I humbly appreciate any positive feedback and help I get here at stackoverflow.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="tick" type="checkbox">

var tick = document.getElementById("tick");

function onChange(evt) {
    alert("Checkbox is " + (evt.target.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked"));
}

document.addEventListener("change", onChange, false);


console.log(tick.checked);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/wRssV/)

This is running on an event but checking the tickbox is just a matter of getting the value from `tick.checked`

As I said, I don't understand what your code is doing in the small amount of context that you have supplied but perhaps this is what you want, changing your textbox check to a checkbox check

```
if (form.tick.checked) {
      form.generator.value +="<meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"" +
      form.input10.value + "\">\n"; 
}
```

Comment: my problem is that it generates code when checked instead of having to click the generate code button, I would appreciate further help if you have the time.

Comment: If you post your jsfiddle that demonstrates your code and the problem then we could suggest a specific solution but from the code in your question, I am unable to help further.

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer to your own question when you are happy. Do you have some html that accompanies that code? or am I supposed to guess it? :)

Comment: congrats on your success! :)

Comment: well i put that code in replace where the alert was and thought it did the trick, but when you click generate code it generates code for that checkbox whether or not its checked or not..